# VM azure and web application in same network

Tags: azure, web-applications, virtual-machine

I'm setting up my environment in azure and I´d to know how I can put my VM on the same network as my application server (web sites)?

Currently, there is a big latency between my database (on VM) and my application (on web sites).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them to the same Virtual Network, to add a VM to a virtual network in the old portal remember to choose to "Create from gallery" as that is the only place where you can choose virtual network.

In the new portal you can add a website to the Virtual Network when opening the website.

One point worth remembering is that it is a VIRTUAL network, but as it used to be with affinity groups a VNET should make sure that your servers are located "close by"

Answer (score 0):

You can connect Azure Web Applications to VNETs - the best practice is to make sure they are in the same data center.

You're still going to have some latency (more than what you would on your local dev machine) - but as long as they are in the same datacenter region (EAST US, etc), that should minimize latency.

Your database should also not be open to the public (best practices here), and a VNET would solve this problem.